# What does "15%" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Dom meets Queenie at jewellery shop:

> Queenie: You do the driving, I'll cut you in for 15%.
>
> Dom: My thieving days are over.
>
> Queenie: Mine ain't.

What does "15%" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queenie is proposing that they rob the store, Dom will get 15% of the take (that is, whatever is stolen) in exchange for being the get-away driver.but Dom declines.